# What needs to be done to change the SIP transport protocol in-between an established dialog?

Tags: sip

Given a SIP dialog (INVITE, 200 OK, ACK) has been established via TCP. How can it be switched to UDP?

*I would assume it could be done via RE-INVITE, changing the Via- and the Contact-Header.*

---

Note that in [rfc3665#3.7#F9](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3665#section-3.7) the RE-INVITE changes the IP address, so I assume the transport protocol could be switched as well..

Comment: I am not sure you can express things like that. 
In an established dialog, the route and/or contact may or may not have an explicit transport tag. 
Without explicit transport stated, there is no switch necessary at all.
Most of time, if the transport is explicitly stated then it must be used for pratical or security reasons.

Comment: "may or may not have an explicit transport tag." -> this question is about explicit setting the transport tag.
"Without explicit transport stated" --> I don't think this is relevant for this question?
"Most of time, if the transport is explicitly stated then it must be used for pratical or security reasons." --> and the other times? :)
Note what @AymericM wrote in his answer sounds plausible to me and is an sufficient answer.

Comment: The other times, it is a wrong configuration or a workaround for corner cases. 
btw my 2 cents, I would use only the UPDATE method; via header modification is hard to manage when SBC are on the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rfc3665#3.7#F9](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3665#section-3.7) does not help for your use-case because it focus on explaining what's happening when the **IP for media needs to be updated**.

Every SIP transaction is independent and any transport can be used for each of them. However, if you update a dialog (transport, contact), **it can be done by re-INVITE, but may also be done via UPDATE**.

> I would assume it could be done via RE-INVITE, changing the Via- and
> the Contact-Header.

This looks correct to me. In practice:

```
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX;branch=z9hG4bKlkld5l
Contact: <sip:bob@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXX>
```

should be modified to

```
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:YYYY;branch=z9hG4bKlkld5l
Contact: <sip:bob@YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:YYYY>
```

And in real life, you could also use and/or mofidy **transport=UDP in Contact** and **rport parameter in Via**.

SIDENOTE: Switching from TCP to UDP is strongly not recommended. Only switching from UDP to TCP is supposed to provide benefits.

Answer (score 0):

You can switch freely between transports when sending (or receiving) SIP messages. Even within a dialog. The type of transport isn't set for a dialog when it is established.

The type of transport used for a certain message can indeed be reflected in the Via and Contact headers, URIs etc. But that doesn't mean a SIP message with 'UDP' in the Via header has been sent/received via UDP: if a TCP connection exists between 2 SIP endpoints it makes perfect sense to use this connection for UDP messages too. Upgrading the transport is always allowed, downgrading isn't.

The only thing you have to keep in mind is security. When using sips-URIs, TLS etc. this can/will place restrictions on the type of transport you are allowed to use for communication.

Comment: This might be true for the switch from UDP to TCP, but not necessarily vice versa - therefore I don't think this answer is accurate - from RFC 3261:
`For any port and interface that a server listens on for UDP, it MUST listen on that same port and interface for TCP. This is because a message may need to be sent using TCP, rather than UDP, if it is too large. As a result, the converse is not true. A server need not listen for UDP on a particular address and port just because it is listening on that same address and port for TCP.`
How should the UDP port be found if it differs to the TCP port?

Comment: That is of course correct. When establishing a dialog using TCP there is no guarantee that UDP messages sent within that dialog will reach the remote target. But if you want to switch to UDP, as stated in your question, you can always send a UDP message and see if you get a response. That is allowed (although maybe not recommended).